# Chrome extension is blocking my Javascript

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

This started happening out of the blue. I'm a front-end dev and work in the Chrome dev tools a lot changing CSS/JS.

In the last week or so, if I work on a site with the dev tools open for 10 minutes or so, the "Paused in debugger" dialog comes up as if I had put a debugger statement in my JS, but it seems to be coming from a Chrome extension:

[image]

When I click the "play" button (which normally allows JS execution to continue), the dialog clears but the whole page just sort of freezes, and I have to close and reopen the tab. This has never happened to me before, and after Googling a bit about extensions I'm not sure how to troubleshoot.

Comment: Out of curiousity, what is the error message that you're receiving?

Comment: "Attempting to use a disconnected port object"